# I do not have permission to install new software

Tags: lubuntu

After I wiped my drive and reinstalled Lubuntu, I noticed that I could not install new software. When I selected a program to install, I got a message saying "you do not have permission to install ''.

How do I get permission?  (In previous versions of Lubuntu, I could install whatever I wanted.)

FYI, here's a description of my Linux system:

```
-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 4.13.0-39-generic (i686)
Version     : #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 14:21:12 UTC 2018
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.26-0ubuntu2.1) 2.26
Distribution        : Ubuntu 17.10
-Current Session-
Computer Name       : rogerc-ThinkPad-H
User Name       : rogerc (Roger Chapanis)
Language        : en_US.UTF-8 (en_US)
Home Directory      : /home/rogerc
-Misc-
Uptime      : 5 hours 45 minutes
Load Average        : 0.87, 1.20, 1.28
Available entropy in /dev/random        : 3822 bits (healthy)
```

Comment: You did not log in with your admin account? Or forgot about sudo? Can you give us the actual command and error notice (copy/paste it into the question please(

Comment: Can you run from terminal whoami? Then id here output of whoami from terminal. or just    id $whoami from the terminal and add the output of that commands in your questions.

Comment: In response to "whoami," I see "rogerc"

Comment: From System Tools, I chose "Software".  The featured application (Corebird) displayed. Then, I clicked "Productivity," clicked "Finance," clicked "LibreOffice Calc," and then clicked "Install."  Immediately, the following message appeared: "unable to install LibreOffice Calc; you do not have permission to install software"

Answer (score 2):

Install policykit-1-gnome

```
sudo apt install policykit-1-gnome
```

Open Terminal and launch gnome-software with sudo

```
sudo gnome-software
```

If this works for you, you can grant ownership of gnome-software run it without having to sudo it.(replace  with your own username)

```
sudo chown <user>:<user> /usr/bin/gnome-software
```

Now you can use it without any issue.

This works for me in 18.04

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to log out and log back in or something?  Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that running gnome-software using sudo is not appropriate, since it would run it with more permissions than necessary. Elevated permissions is necessary to install software, but should not be needed for the UI itself.

To me the issue was resolved, on 20.04, after I re-installed gnome-software.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-software
```